# SWRevealViewController segue get stuck only with 1 button

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swrevealviewcontroller

I've created an app in which I need to log-in in 2 ways:
- Facebook Login,
- Normal Login (email, password).

I've added FBLogin with Facebook SDK and modified a button in order to not use fb default button. I've added a segue (Present Modally) from my loginView to anotherView with a segue (called "fb_login") and set segue class to "SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController".

Now, I've do the same thing with my LogIn button. changed identifier and set segue class, but when i push it my app get stuck (with no error on xCode) so I need to close it and reopen it.

I've tried to change segue type from "Preset Modally" to "reveal view Controller set controller", but nothing changed (it don't get stuck, but it doesn't work).

This is the function on Login button pressed:

```
@IBAction func loginButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var email = emailTextField.text
    var password = passwordTextField.text
    let urlString = "..."

    let urlwithPercentEscapes = urlString.addingPercentEncoding( withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)


    let url = URL(string: urlwithPercentEscapes!)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else {
            do {
                //PARSEDDATA CONTIENE TUTTE LE TUPLE
                let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
                let temp = parsedData["user"] as! NSArray
                var userLogin = temp[0] as! NSDictionary
                if((userLogin["login"]) as! Int == 1){ //login successfully
                    self.user.name = userLogin["name"]! as! String
                    self.user.surname = userLogin["surname"]! as! String
                    self.user.email = userLogin["email"]! as! String
                    self.user.url_image = userLogin["profile_img_url"]! as! String
                    self.user.id_user = Int(userLogin["id_user"]! as! String)!
                    self.user.gender = Int(userLogin["gender"]! as! String)!
                    self.user.birthday = userLogin["birthday"]! as! String
                    self.user.id_license = userLogin["id_license"]! as! String
                    self.user.registration_date = userLogin["registration_date"]! as! String
                    self.user.expire_date = userLogin["expire_date"]! as! String
                    self.user.mac_address = userLogin["mac_address"]! as! String
                    self.user.license_key = userLogin["license_key"]! as! String
                    self.user.license_type = Int(userLogin["license_type"]! as! String)!
                    sleep(2)
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "normal_login", sender: nil)
                }else{ //login failed
                    print("login failed")
                }


            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }

    }).resume()
}
```

thank you all guys! (I'm using Swift 3.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is happening because you are trying to manipulate the UI from a background thread. You should always do UI related manipulations on Main thread only.

Try with:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async
{
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "normal_login", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: @CarloDiDomenico: You are welcome. Glad to hear that it helped you to solve the issue. Happy Coding !!!